Bootstrap chef issues
I have a strange issue when trying to bootstrap nodes and upload new cookbook versions at Ubuntu.
We had an old chef server which run in RHEL, but the different between the two operations is now new Chef is pulling instead of pushing in the RHEL.
For example:
root@server:~/chef-repo# knife bootstrap <server> --node-name <server> -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa --ssh-verify-host-key never --run-list 'role[XXX]' -y
Connecting to <XXX> using ssh
WARN: Server returned error **500 ** for https://XXX/organizations/XXX/nodes/XXX, retrying 1/5 in 4s
WARN: Server returned error **503 ** for https://XXX/organizations/XXX/clients, retrying 4/5 in 32s

OR

ERROR: You authenticated successfully to https://XXX/organizations/XXX as admin but you are not authorized for this action.
Response: Failed to verify user 'admin' as a member of organization 'XXX'

I tried to add a validation certification at:
~/chef/.chef/config.rb

I also tried adding port 443 in the chef_server_url
chef_server_url          "https://XXX:443/organizations/XXX"

Sometime after restart the service chef-server-ctl restart or even reboot of the CM server I has able to run, but after a few minutes the issue return back.
It may related that I have a lot of TCP connections
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59000         127.0.0.1:8000          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          127.0.0.1:36098         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37460         127.0.0.1:8000          TIME_WAIT  

I have over of 3000 TIME_WAIT connections waiting.

You need to add your admin user as a member of the organization as the error says.
chef-server-ctl org-user-add ORG_NAME USER_NAME (options)
https://docs.chef.io/server_users/

root@XXX:~# chef-server-ctl org-user-add XXX admin
WARN: Server returned error 500 for https://127.0.0.1/organizations/XXX/association_requests, retrying 1/5 in 3s
User admin already associated with organization XXX
Thanks

BTW - when I type "chef-server-ctl user-list", I don't see the admin user..
root@XXX:~# chef-server-ctl user-list
WARN: Server returned error 503 for https://127.0.0.1/users, retrying 1/5 in 3s
admin
pivotal

root@XXX:~# chef-server-ctl check-config
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 16.17.51
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["infra-server::config"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:

yum-epel (4.5.0)
infra-server (0.1.2)
enterprise (1.2.0)
packagecloud (1.0.1)
runit (5.1.7)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 04 seconds

Hi,
What is the best approach to regenerate the "admin.pem" file?
Is it right maybe the issue is with this?
